# Schroedinger Equation in the interaction picture with a nilpotent algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions, time-evolution

I consider a Hamiltonian describing the interaction between a system and a bath, namely $H = H_0^S + H_0^B + H_I$. In the interaction picture, the Schroedinger equation for the unitary operator $U_I(t,t_0) = U_0(t,t_0) U(t,t_0)$ is
\begin{equation}
i \partial_t {U}_I(t,t') = \mathcal{H}^{int}_I(t) {U}_I(t,t').
\end{equation}
We know that a formal solution of this is given by the time-chronological operator 
$$
U_I (t,t') = \mathcal{T} e^{-i\int_{t'}^t \mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s) ds}
$$
In the case of nilpotent algebra of the operator $\mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s)$ evaluated at different times  (i.e. $[\mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s),[\mathcal{H}^{int}_I(t),\mathcal{H}^{int}_I(v)]]=0$) one can try to use the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorf formula to find the solution of Schroedinger equation. Indeed, if we take as an ansatz the unitary operator
$$
U_I (t,t') = e^{-i\int_{t'}^t \mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s) ds}
$$
we easily seen that it is a solution but it does not satisfy the semigroup property $U(t,t')U(t',0) = U(t,0)$. Using the BCH formula and considering a nilpotent algebra as stated before, we can modify the latter and find that 
$$
U_I (t,t') = e^{\overbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \int_{t'}^t ds_1 \int_{t'}^t ds_2 [\mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s_1),\mathcal{H}_I^{int}(s_2)] \theta(s_1-s_2)}^{\phi(t,t')}}e^{-i\int_{t'}^t \mathcal{H}^{int}_I(s) ds} 
\tag{1}
$$
One can verify that in case of nilpotent algebra this indeed satisfy the semigroup property. However, it does not satisfy anymore the Schroedinger equation since if we evaluate the time partial derivative we obtain
$$
i \partial_t U_I(t,t') = \mathcal{H}^{int}_I(t) U_I(t,t') - U_I(t,t') \partial_t \phi(t,t')
$$
Sinche in general $\phi(t,t')$ does depend on time, it seems to me that there is something wrong in my deduction. However, the solution of this problem can be found in the Breuer Petruccione (Chapter 4, Section 2).

> I wonder if there are different paths to prove that equation (1) is
>   true, since in the Breuer Petruccione this is given as the solution,
>   or in general, if there is a way to correctly expand the time
>   chronological order in case of nilpotent algebra

Comment: raskolnikov - I edited the question to use the `\tag{1}` syntax for the equation number. This right-justifies the equation number, making it easier to see.

Comment: Do your operator  equations in your very first paragraph square with [standard stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture)?

Comment: Yes, sure. If you take for instance the time evolution of the density matrix $\rho_I(t) = U_I(t)^* \rho_I(0) U_I(t) $ and put it in the formula from the corresponding wiki section, you obtain two equations (one the hermitian conjugate of the other) which match with the differential equation for the unitary operator

Comment: $U_I(t,0)= U_0^{-1}(t,0)U(t,0)$.

Comment: You don't need CBH, you need [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map).

Comment: "we easily see that it is a solution..." is simply false. You are misconstruing derivatives of exponentials. That is precisely why Dyson's time-order product was invented.

Comment: Oh thanks! Indeed, if I use the formula in the wiki for the derivative of an exponential map, I see that for a nilpotent algebra like the one is generated from the $\mathcal{H}_I^{int}(t)$ in the fraction with the adjoint maps, due to series expansion, remains only the first two terms, and the second one exactly cancel out the second term $-U_I(t,t') \partial_t \phi(t,t')$. So you are right, the ansatz is not a solution, the only solution is the (1) and it can be verified using the (real) derivative of exponential map! Thank you very much :)